# Is it possible to create a custom one-to-one relationship in Hibernate between a table and a view in Postgres?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a table and a view in the database (Postgres). The business relationship between them is one-to-one. However, I CANNOT modify the database to create any constraint.

The table is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice
(
  invoiceid text NOT NULL,
  date_created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT invoice_pkey PRIMARY KEY (invoiceid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

and the view is something like:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW invoice_view AS 
    SELECT invoice.invoiceid, invoice.date_created,
    .......
    FROM invoice;
```

Can I create a custom one-to-one relationship in Hibernate so I can use something like `myInvoice.getInvoiceView();`? If it is possible, How to do it?

I am using the XML configuraiton. If anyone can provide me an answer using annotations, it will be also great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Hibernate does not care whether the entities are mapped to tables or views:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "invoiceid")
  private String id;

  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private InvoiceView invoiceView;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice_view")
public class InvoiceView {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "invoiceid")
  private String id;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I actually have managed to map the view to Java. But I failed to map the relationship between the table and the view since there is NO relationship in the database. I will give your method a try later as I have not used annotations before. Then I probably can find its XML equivalence.